# Responsive and retinized avatars with SRCSET and SIZES attribute

Tags: html, responsive-design

I need an avatar image that will be 30x30 on mobile and 40x40 on tablets/desktops. It also has to be @1x and @2x sizes for non-retina and retina screens.

I am trying this code:

```
<img
     srcset="mobile.jpg     30w,
             desktop.jpg    40w,
             mobile@2x.jpg  60w,
             desktop@2x.jpg 80w
            "
     sizes="(min-width: 768px) 40px, 30px"
     src="desktop.jpg"
>
```

It works perfectly in Firefox, Safari and Edge. It doesn't work at all in Opera. In Chrome on MACOSX it works only if I run developer tool. In Chrome on Windows it worked once until I open developer tool.

When I say that it doesn't work I mean that browsers always get largest image. From the other side they change size on the page correct.

So first thing I want to know is my code correct? Maybe I just don't get it and do something wrong?

Thanks.

**UPD:** I tried to create fiddle or pen, but there is some troubles with loading images. Anyway here is a link: http://codepen.io/shchukin/pen/yJbaLA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Opera have a source selection algorithm that favors cached image candidates. This should explain, why you always see the largest loaded.

About your general purpose. For an image that is always below 100 pixel, `srcset` doesn't make too much sense. The difference between 40pixel and 80pixel is to small. Simply give all users a 60 or 80pixel image and it should be fine.

Comment: What kind of cache are we talking? If I refresh page with CTRL+F5 or CMD+SHIFT+R largest images is still there. But seems like I just have to believe. So my code is correct? Thanks.